# Two variables Taylor's polynomial (second order) in terms of differential of the function?

Tags: taylor-expansion

here's the doubt I have: Is it possible to express Taylor's polynomial in terms of the differential of the function (at least in the two dimentional case)? For instance:

Let's call $f: D\subset\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f\in C^2(D)$ and $x_o \in D$ and $\vec{h} = (x-x_0, y-y_0)$.

Then my books reports this ($Hf(x_0)$ is the Hessian Matrix of $f$ in $x_0$):

$f(x) = f(x_0) + \vec{\nabla} f|_{x_0} \cdot \vec{h} + \frac{1}{2} \vec{h}^t Hf(x_o)\vec{h} + o(|h^2|)$

To my unexpert eye this looks like

$f(x) = f(x_0) +df(x_o,h) + \frac{1}{2}d^2f(x_0,h) + o(|h^2|)$

Am I wrong? I didn't find anything on internet cause I don't actually know what to type to look for it...

Comment: The very definition of Taylor expansion shows that a function is written as the sum of its derivatives. Sometimes only the first few terms are written, with the $o$ notation indicating that the others are negligible. What is your specific question?

Comment: @BillWallis: My question is:

is $f(x) = f(x_0) +df(x_o,h) + \frac{1}{2}d^2f(x_0,h) + o(|h^2|)$ a correct definition for the second order polynomial?

Comment: You just need to be a bit careful about how you expand the $d^2$, the coefficients depend on whether you take the same derivative twice or not.

Comment: A reference is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Here's my expansion for $d^2f(x_0,h) := \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}|_{x_0}h_i h_j$